# hello i want create tsne plot by my dataset in R . but when i write commands i get this error

Tags: r

```
library(Rtsne)

setwd("n/g")

expression_data <- read.table(file = "zdata.matrix.xlsx", row.names = 1, sep=',', header = T)
meta_data <- read.table(file = "atac_v1_pbmc_10k_singlecell.xlsx", row.names = 1, sep=',', header = T)

tsne_realData <- Rtsne(expression_data, perplexity=10, check_duplicates = FALSE)

# Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : 
#  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Comment: I briefly looked at the [Rtsne package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/Rtsne.pdf) and the `Rtsne()` function requires the data format to be a matrix. Try converting `expression_data` to a matrix before passing it to the Rtsne function.

Comment: i change my files name to exp.mat & meta.mat but problem was not solved

Comment: You need a matrix in R, you don't need to do anything to the file structure. Create a new object and use the `as.matrix()` function and put that object into the Rtsne function. See my answer.

Comment: i do not know how to work this function please show me another way

Comment: see my answer to your question

Comment: tanks a lot my previous error solved

Comment: glad that worked. Also accept answer so question can be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked at the [Rtsne package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/Rtsne.pdf) and the Rtsne() function requires the data format to be a matrix. Try converting expression_data to a matrix before passing it to the Rtsne function. You can do so like this:

```
library(Rtsne)

setwd("n/g")

expression_data <- read.table(file = "zdata.matrix.xlsx", row.names = 1, sep=',', header = T)
meta_data <- read.table(file = "atac_v1_pbmc_10k_singlecell.xlsx", row.names = 1, sep=',', header = T)
expression_matrix <- as.matrix(expression_data)

tsne_realData <- Rtsne(expression_matrix, perplexity=10, check_duplicates = FALSE)
```